# how to write setTimeout with params by Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, coffeescript

Please tell me how to write javascript below in coffeescript.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    something(param);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: how can we add .call('hello') to this

Answer (score 214, accepted):

I think it's a useful convention for callbacks to come as the last argument to a function. This is usually the case with the Node.js API, for instance. So with that in mind:

```
delay = (ms, func) -> setTimeout func, ms

delay 1000, -> something param
```

Granted, this adds the overhead of an extra function call to every `setTimeout` you make; but in today's JS interpreters, the performance drawback is insignificant unless you're doing it thousands of times per second. (And what are you doing setting thousands of timeouts per second, anyway?)

Of course, a more straightforward approach is to simply name your callback, which tends to produce more readable code anyway (jashkenas is a big fan of this idiom):

```
callback = -> something param
setTimeout callback, 1000
```

Comment: Great unless you need nested callbacks

Answer (score 184):

```
setTimeout ( ->
  something param
), 1000
```

The parentheses are optional, but starting the line with a comma seemed messy to me.

Comment: Take out the parens, and have a cup of coffee ,~)

Comment: Does not compile with the parentheses for me. I had to remove them, start the line with a comma, and it works like a charm.

Comment: With parentheses you can also do this in one line.

Comment: @JeremyThille note that the space in between `setTimeout` and the opening paren is important. The space there means the parentheses are surrounding the closure as the first parameter to setTimeout; if it was directly after the t then coffescript would expect the parentheses to enclose both parameters.

Answer (score 67):

```
setTimeout -> 
  something param
, 1000
```

Comment: This is the best if you just want to use an anonymous function.

Comment: also for a named function, setTimeout namedFunc, 5000

Comment: Note that whitespace is important. The call must be spaced exactly as above. If `something param` is on the same line as `setTimeout`, it gets parsed differently.

Answer (score 46):

This will result in a roughly equivalent translation (thanks @Joel Mueller):

```
setTimeout (-> something param), 1000
```

Note that this isn't an exact translation because the anonymous function returns the result of calling `something(param)` instead of undefined, as in your snippet.

Comment: Too many parens/semicolons! This is CoffeeScript, getting rid of excess parens is half the point. `setTimeout (() -> something param), 1000`

Comment: Nicholas makes a good point that the empty parens are also optional.

Answer (score 12):

I find this the best method to do the same,

```
setTimeout (-> alert "hi"), 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

another option:

```
setTimeout(
    -> something param
    1000
)
```