# In CoffeeScript, how can you make a function call with anonymous functions as parameters?

Tags: coffeescript

The following gives a syntax error related to the anonymous function:

```
my_function = (f, x, str) ->
  alert str + f(x)

my_function (x) -> 1 + x, 12, "The answer is: "
```

The following works:

```
my_function = (f, x, str) ->
  alert str + f(x)

increment = (x) -> x + 1

my_function increment, 12, "The answer is: "
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463052/how-to-pass-two-anonymous-functions-as-arguments-in-coffescript. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459630/how-to-write-settimeout-with-params-by-coffeescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_function ((x) -> x + 1), 12, "The answer is: "
```

That should fix it.