# CoffeeScript, pass multiple parameters including an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am not sure how to write this in CS. maybe some1 can help:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {} , {scope : scope})
```

thanks.

Comment: ive tried nothing... and im all out of ideas man.. :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720402/in-coffeescript-how-can-you-make-a-function-call-with-anonymous-functions-as-pa

Comment: @d4rklit3 if I were you I would back off coffeescript for a while and try to get a good grasp of javascript first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass two anonymous functions as arguments in CoffeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463052/how-to-pass-two-anonymous-functions-as-arguments-in-coffescript)

Comment: @RicardoTomasi i read your comment. and i disagree with you. perhaps you should be more tactful. just some friendly real world advice for you buddy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would write some CoffeeScript like so...

```
FB.getLoginStatus(
  (response) -> 
    doSomething()
  {scope: scope})
```

Which would convert to the JavaScript like so...

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  return doSomething();
}, {
  scope: scope
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry my quick sample doesn't meet your requirements for perfect.

Comment: You're forgiven. `FB.getLoginStatus receiveLogin, { scope }`

Answer (score 4):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {}, {
  scope: scope
});
```

in JavaScript is:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(
  (response) ->
  { scope }
)
```

in CoffeeScript.

To answer your question about multiple parameters further have a look at these examples:

```
$('.main li').hover(
  -> $(@).find('span').show()   
  -> $(@).find('span').hide()
)
```

In CoffeeScript equals to:

```
$('.main li').hover(function() {
  return $(this).find('span').show();
}, function() {
  return $(this).find('span').hide();
});
```

in JavaScript.

An even simpler example regarding handling multiple parameters (without anonymous functions) would be:

```
hello = (firstName, lastName) ->
  console.log "Hello #{firstName} #{lastName}"

hello "Coffee", "Script"
```

in CoffeeScript compiles to:

```
var hello;

hello = function(firstName, lastName) {
  return console.log("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName);
};

hello("Coffee", "Script");
```

in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(((response) ->),{scope})
```